# How to use radio button in angular 2 and post the value using post call?

Tags: html, typescript, angular, radio-button

I am beginner in angular 2

> **Here is my HTML**

```
<form action="POST" (submit)="register()" class="aa-login-form">
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="gender" name="sex" value="MALE"> Male
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="gender" name="sex" value="FEMALE"> Female
</form>
```

> While clicking a radio button error appears as below,
>   [Error showing on clicking on radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECIfe.png)
>
> Here is my component

```
 import { Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';

    @Component({ 
        templateUrl: 'gender.html'
    })

export class LoginComponent{
gender:string;
constructor(private _http:Http){ }
register(){
this._http.post('some_url',this.gender)
.subscribe((response) => {console.log("VALUE RECEIVED:        "+JSON.stringify(response));},(err) => {console.log("ERROR: "+err); },() => {
console.log("REGISTER SUCCESS");});
}
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log()` to debug what happens to your `this.gender` variable? Can you post these results?

Comment: On clicking radio button it is giving error and on console it is showing "undefind".

Comment: Alright, have you tried `console.log()` to show you the full `this` object?

Comment: You could use the `(change)` event instead of '[(ngModel)]', something like this `<input type="radio" (change)="gender = this['value']"  `

Comment: Have you tried adding `value="<valueOnClick>"` to your inputs? it says that the value is undefined. Because you're using ngModel, your doing two way databinding but gender doesn't have a value at first so maybe you should try initializing it

Comment: See this answer for a different way of accomplishing what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282904/i-cant-get-the-values-for-radio-buttons-in-angular-2-forms?rq=1

Comment: @AngJobs  same error persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the RadioButton Values with a (click)="" attribute without form:

```
<input type="radio"  name="sex" (click)="register('MALE')"> Male
<input type="radio"  name="sex" (click)="register('FEMALE')"> Female
```

then change your component to :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  opts: RequestOptions;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    var headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    this.opts = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  }

  register(gender:string){
    console.log(gender);
    let json = JSON.stringify(gender);
    this.http.post('some_url', json, this.opts)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log("VALUE RECEIVED:        "+response);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("ERROR: "+err);
        },
        () => {
        console.log("REGISTER SUCCESS");});
  }
}
```

This answer uses angular-cli, if you don't know how how to use it with your seed-project, please write a comment with which seed you are using.

Comment: i don't get it, what seed is?

Comment: with what you started your project - the initial structure, npm, maybe gulp/grunt, typings etc.

Comment: well  i have used npm